# Java equivalent for the Numpy multi-dimensional object

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, numpy

After using it for a while, I really like the Numpy multi-dimensional array. It's helpful to write algorithms with a concise yet readable and fairly general code. I wish to have the same thing in Java. Before coding a multi-dimensional array with a Numpy-like API myself, is there such a thing already ?

[PS] I searched a bit, did not see

Comment: If you are referring to the Java *platform*, [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala) looks like a good candidate...

Comment: You don't need Scala.  Those multi-dimensional data structures you refer to are matricies.  You need a linear algebra library, like LA4J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the closest match seems to be Colt ! http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

It features a multi-dimensional array object, views over an array and your usual linear algebra ! And it's seems to be rather efficient.

Comment: Can you please answer, which class of Colt represents multidimensional array?

Comment: @Dims the interface for multidimensional arrays is AbstractMatrix http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/AbstractMatrix.html. Implementations provided in Colt cover only 1, 2 and 3 dimensional cases.

Comment: @dlegland so it is far from being equivalent to `numpy`.

Answer (score 20):

The OP is from 2011. So as of end of 2015 I would like mention that there is a new kid in town which claims to be numpy for java -> [nd4j](http://nd4j.org/). The nice thing is that nd4j is an abstraction layer on top of different libraries like blas. Depending on the size of your matrices there are underlying implementations twice as [fast](http://nd4j.org/benchmarking.html) as numpy or jblas. And your code is real platform independent.

Comment: Unfortunately, even 4 years later, ND4j is quite poorly documented.

Comment: Even an operation as basic as broadcasting is not clearly documented. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/60143939 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42309075

Comment: Hi, would you mind filing an issue on this where we can see it https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues ? That would be a much more productive discussion.  We are happy to address individual needs and know we can always improve (just like any OSS project really)

Comment: nd4j link is broken as of today.

Comment: @theprogrammer https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/nd4j/basics

Answer (score 13):

The library **Vectorz** (https://github.com/mikera/vectorz) offers a fully featured NDArray that is broadly equivalent in functionality to Numpy's NDArray, i.e. it offers the fullowing features:

- Arbitrary **N-dimensional arrays** of numeric values (in this case, Java doubles)
- Lightweight views using **strided access** for efficient slicing
- A broad range of mathematical **operations** with effiecient implementations

It's also very fast: it is much faster then NumPy for most operations, although NumPy may still be faster for certain *large matrix operations* because it uses the native BLAS libraries to accelerate these.

Here's the NDArray class itself:

https://github.com/mikera/vectorz/blob/develop/src/main/java/mikera/arrayz/NDArray.java

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of Vectorz

Comment: Numpy can be compiled with native BLAS support, e.g. OpenBlas or ATLAS. Vectorz takes advantage of some optimized linear algebra library?

Comment: Vectorz does not support native libraries - it's deliberately designed to be pure JVM code. There are other Java libraries (e.g. MTJ, JBlas) that can use BLAS.

Comment: Hi Mike. I found Vectorz very attractive to me. I am working on color format transformation from RGB to HSL in real time and think that Vectorz exactly what I need. Is it possible to apply some mathematical expression to every element in matrix in efficient way? Assuming that a matrix is a representation of the single camera frame, lets say 2D array.

Comment: @Yuriy there is an `applyOp` function that lets you apply arbitrary (including custom) operations to entire arrays. Worth looking into.

Comment: Why is Vectorz deliberately designed to not use native and/or GPU code?

Comment: is there any alternative to numpy`s hstack function in Vectorz.I am looking for such implementation.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky there's nothing to stop Vectorz using the GPU. In fact I have an experimental OpenCL implementation here: https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-opencl

Comment: @RavikantTiwari you can use a.join(b,1) to join along columns (with 1 being the column dimension, 0 for rows)

Answer (score 4):

You can use numerical libraries for linear algebra; those will have matricies in them.  Have a look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/).

Comment: I'm aware of that library. The API is a classic 'vector & matrix' one. I'm looking for one with a Numpy like one, which provides multi-dimensional arrays, unifying vectors and matrices as one entity. Such an approach, based on personal experience, turns out to make many math code easier to write.

Comment: Vectorz (see my answer) provides arbitrary multi-dimensional arrays with a single interface abstraction (INDArray) that is is implemented by both vectors and matrices

Answer (score 2):

Scala has a wider number of numpy-like libraries, if that counts. (You should even be able to use them from Java.)

[BIDMat](https://github.com/BIDData/BIDMat/wiki/BIDMat-Quick-Reference) promises to be both powerful and fast (and GPU-powered).

As already mentioned, there is also [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just thought I'd add these two Java ndarray libraries:

- [TensorFlow NdArray Java Library](https://github.com/tensorflow/java-ndarray)
- [AWS Deep Java NdArray Library](https://javadoc.io/static/ai.djl/api/0.12.0/ai/djl/ndarray/package-frame.html)

Comment: Just noting that the TF Java NdArray library is maintained by the TensorFlow org but can be added tonany Java project and does not depend on the TensorFlow itself (the equivalent of an `NdArray` backed by TensorFlow is a `Tensor` in TensorFlow Java)

Answer (score 1):

Another great option is to use Spark’s DataFrame API.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

This gives you a Pandas/Numpy like interface to arrays in Java. Plus the code is inherently parallelizable and can be run on a cluster of machines if your data size increases.

Answer (score 1):

Java is rather clumsy for nd-arrays (no operator overloading, etc). If Kotlin is OK, you can try Kotlin-NumPy (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-numpy)

nd4j (https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j) was quite popular some time ago, but now it seems not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [la4j](http://la4j.org/), an elegant, modern linear algebra library, or [JBLAS](http://www.jblas.org/javadoc/index.html), another that ports BLAS to Java.

Answer (score -4):

I would say that java has nothing 'like' numpy.  numpy is a large mathematical oriented project which does not really fit in java mentality.

It does not meen that there is no good collection libraries in java!  Guava has the [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html) interface with two good implementations, [ArrayTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html) and [HashBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html).  It's more a collection library that a mathematical tool but it's very useful.

For speed and memory efficiency, threre is [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/).  A collection library that works with primitives.

For maticies operations, [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) seems good.

As far as I know, you will need to code more and to use more library in java than python.

Comment: Hum... Why wouldn't a mathematically oriented project fit in in Java mentality?